# Windows blocking python urllib from downloading

Tags: python, windows, python-requests, urllib

I'm using Python and `urllib.requests` to download an image from a website and I'm doing so constantly downloading for some tests. But for some reason `urllib` just stops downloading. I've run this script on a Raspberry Pi 3 with no issues what so ever.

Does Windows 7 block or terminate such process because of consuming bandwidth? 
If so, how do I make it so windows doesn't do that.

This is my code:

```py
import urllib, requests
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import *

url = 'url'
username = 'admin'
password = 'password'
filename = 'image.jpg'
r = requests.get(url, auth=(username,password))
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
        for bits in r.iter_content(): out.write(bits)
```

Comment: how have you written the requests? show us the code

Comment: @CanciuCostin I added my code now! Thanks

Comment: Your code look fine. You could check maybe the provider is limiting the access to that specific resource. You didn't provide however the status code or the error you get. Maybe the image is too big and you just have to add a timeout to the request

Comment: @CanciuCostin The URL is a IP address that has an image, its on a local internet connection, more specifically the IP is to a camera. After about running the script for roughly half an hour, it crashes, theirs no error or anything it just stops.